# Error @types/ws Type 'Server' is not generic after updating from angular 9 to 15 step by step

Tags: angular, typescript, angular15

Getting below error after performing `ng serve`

Error:

```
Error: node_modules/@types/ws/index.d.ts:328:18 - error TS2315: Type 'Server' is not generic.

328         server?: HTTPServer<V> | HTTPSServer<V> | undefined;
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@types/ws/index.d.ts:328:34 - error TS2315: Type 'Server' is not generic.

328         server?: HTTPServer<V> | HTTPSServer<V> | undefined;
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

i have installed `@types/node:12.20.55` and `@types/ws:8.5.4` but still getting the same error.

Comment: I have fixed this issue. by uninstalling `@types/node:12.20.55` and Clearing the Angular cache. After clearing the cache you need to perform npm install again.